# Calling function inside jsx in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to learn React and I'm working on this page and I'm stuck. I have a component class and I cannot get this to work:

```
staffList() {
    // Do computation here to generate list
    return (
        <div>Awesome list here</div>
    );
}

render() {
    return(
        <div className="content staff">
            {this.staffList}
        </div>
    );
}
```

When I try to run this code the page doesn't display 'awesome div here'.

On the online React course I took I remember the teacher doing something similar to this, what am I missing?

I tried to Google vaguely but I don't know what to search for to find more.

Comment: You have to execute the function: `{this.staffList()}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the `()` with function `staffList`, write it like this:

```
staffList() {
    // Do computation here to generate list
    return (
        <div>Awesome list here</div>
    );
}

render() {
    return(
        <div className="content staff">
            {this.staffList()}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Check this snippet to understand the diff:

```js
function abc() {
  console.log('calling function');
  return "done";
}

// with ()
console.log('abc() = ', abc())

// without ()
console.log('abc = ', abc)
```